# how to Create Array Group

Tags: php, arrays

How can I group values inside the Array and as an example, I want to get it like this

```
[1]=>array(
   ["type"] => 1
   ["amount"] => array(2500,200,5000,400)
)
[2]=>array(
   ["type"] => 2
   ["amount"] => array(4500,500,5000,400)
)
```

Comment: what exactly you want ? you want to create array as you shown?

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code for that :-

```
$ps = array();
$ps[]=array("type" => 1,  "amount" => array(2500,200,5000,400));
$ps[]=array("type" => 2 ,  "amount" => array(4500,500,5000,400));

print_r($ps);
```